# What is different between "normal" and "dangerous" in android protection level

Tags: android, security, permissions

As I read from developer guild in google website
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

> **"normal"**
>   The default value. A lower-risk permission that gives
>   requesting applications access to isolated application-level features,
>   with minimal risk to other applications, the system, or the user. The
>   system automatically grants this type of permission to a requesting
>   application at installation, without asking for the user's explicit
>   approval (though the user always has the option to review these
>   permissions before installing).
>
> **"dangerous"** 
>   A higher-risk permission that would give a requesting
>   application access to private user data or control over the device
>   that can negatively impact the user. Because this type of permission
>   introduces potential risk, the system may not automatically grant it
>   to the requesting application. **For example, any dangerous permissions
>   requested by an application may be displayed to the user and require
>   confirmation before proceeding**, or some other approach may be taken to
>   avoid the user automatically allowing the use of such facilities.

I know what's the meaning for their definition. The difference between them is for "dangerous" level, system may prompt user to approve dangerous permission.

But I want to know, for "dangerous" level, does it really prompt user that any dangerous permissions requested by an application? What I can see is only permission request before installation. Does any example that can prove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> does it really prompt user that any dangerous permissions requested by an application?

In the early days of the Android Market (later renamed the Play Store), if the list of permissions for an app was long, `dangerous` permissions would be shown "above the fold" — only `normal` permissions would be hidden in a "See more" fold-out panel.

The current version of the Play Store does not seem to make much visual distinction between normal and dangerous.

Android 6.0+ devices, for apps with `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher, [will require the developer to explicitly request `dangerous` permissions at runtime](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html), and the user will no longer be prompted for `normal` or `dangerous` permissions at install time.

Comment: So, basically, before Android 6.0, the behavior of normal and dangerous level seems no difference, right?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that ***all permission*** marked as `dangerous` requires runtime permission?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS: Correct, for Android 6.0 and higher.