# Getting list of Permission

Tags: android

Is there anyway to get the list of supported permission of your device/version? Or to check if the permission is supported by the device. I found a code but I think it only compare it on the app permission.

```
 PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        int hasPerm = pm.checkPermission(
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
            this.getPackageName());
        if (hasPerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // do stuff
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

do anyone know to to check the permission if its supported by the device not only the application.

any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Youre code checks if the app has the permission to write to external storage, if I read it right...

To find a list of permissions, those 2 links will help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

[Where can I get a list of Android permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237982/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-android-permissions)

Comment: yes it is. that's why I'm asking how to check the permission if it is supported by the users devices not the app only

Comment: check the 2 links... Manifest.permissions holds the list of permissions.

Comment: I unchecked your answer because I think it only get all the permission of all the app installed on the device. Not all the permission that supported by the device.

Comment: Ok, that's bad... I googled a little bit, found some permission-classes like [java.security.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Permission.html), but I don't know what it does

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there's a method of [PackageManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

```
public abstract List<PermissionGroupInfo> getAllPermissionGroups (int flags)

Retrieve all of the known permission groups in the system.
```

I haven't tried this myself. For a detailed description of the method you can look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getAllPermissionGroups%28int%29).