# How to get all <uses-permission> of other particular application installed on the device (Android)?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I want to get all permission that compare in the Manifest.xml of other application, is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237982/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-android-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't even check if this app is installed on same device...
Google doesn't allow to do this.