# What permissions are necessary for my Android game?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have a simple game on the Google Play Store, but I want to remove some permissions that may be unnecessary.
I want to take out access to "Photos/Media/Files" and "Storage" but I'm wondering if my game would still be able to save. I should probably get rid of "Phone", but I'm not sure if I should take out "Device ID & call information" because I don't want incoming calls to be blocked. Also, would I need access to "Identity" to use 'Google Play Games' service?
Sorry if this is a lot. I've googled the permissions, but I'm still kinda unclear..

Comment: You can still save to internal storage without Photos/Media and Storage. You definitely don't need Phone or Device ID - if your game is running when a call comes through that will be handled by the system app that does have the permissions

Comment: Jhee thanks :). So do I need "Identity" to find accounts on the device such as 'Google', so it can connect to the Play Games service?

Comment: Yes I think you will just need "identity"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237982/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-android-permissions